# Why does Intermediate Value Theorem only consider end-points?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

The IVT says that, given a closed interval of real numbers, $[a, b]$, and a real-valued function $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$, for any point $z\in [f(a), f(b)]$ (WLOG, $f(a) < f(b)$), there exist a point $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = z$.

Now, I'm wondering, why is the theorem only applicable to $z\in[f(a), f(b)]$ and not to $z\in [\min\limits_{x\in [a,b]}\{f(x)\},\max\limits_{x\in [a,b]}\{f(x)\}]$?

Comment: You could use the version of the IVT without intermediate value: The image $f([a,b])$ is an interval.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the Extreme Value Theorem, then you know that $\min(f(x))$ and $\max(f(x))$ (on the interval $[a, b]$) exist; let $a', b'$ realize the minimum and maximum, and apply IVT to $[a', b']$. This shows that - *assuming we already have the EVT* - the version of IVT you describe can be deduced from the standard one.

However, if we *don't* have the EVT yet, we can't argue that $\min(f(x))$ and $\max(f(x))$ exist in the first place, so your version can't even be stated correctly.

So the standard version of IVT has the advantage that it makes sense, and is provable, without first proving EVT. Meanwhile, the on-the-face-of-it stronger version you mention can be deduced from the standard, in the presence of EVT.

Comment: I see. I, for some reason, was implicitly assuming (in the sense of thinking that it is self-evident) that the $\min$ and $\max$ of $f$ do exist on a closed interval.

Comment: @sequence Well, they do! The extreme value theorem is true, after all. But it's not really trivial.

Comment: I feel like it's trivial, but maybe because I don't have enough insight.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the theorem to any closed interval where $f$ is continuous. In particular, to the interval you want.